# C-extensions in DrRacket

Tags: c++, c, racket

I have a working C-extension for Racket. In the Racket CLI and the interactions window of DrRacket it works like a charm. However, I can't get it to work in the definitions window of DrRacket, which would be really useful as that is the interface for my students to develop their programs.

The problem seems to be that definitions in the extension are not 'seen' (or registered or something). The module is loaded (or at least found) but DrRacket complains that it doesn't have execute permission for it, which I don't understand.

In the C code I declared the extension to be a module and I tried both inclusion methods:

(load-extension "racket_extension.so")
  and
(require "racket_extension.rkt") ; which requires you put it in a folder relative to the current working folder as follows:
"compiled/native/x86_64-linux/3m/racket_extension_rkt.so"

Neither method works. The first case gives no error, but the definitions of the external are not registered ("undefined").

In the second case DrRacket gives an error:
  forbidden (execute) access to ....compiled/native/x86_64-linux/3m/racket_extension_rkt.so
but why?

Does anyone have ideas how I can get this to work? What am I missing?

Thanks!
Marc

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I think you are more likely to get an answer if you ask this on the Racket mailing list: http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/

Comment: Thanks Asumu, I will. I've put it on the IRC channel but no response so far.

Answer (score 0):

How are you compiling and linking your extension? Are you using the raco ctool or gcc? Are you executing DrRacket within the same directory as your compiled directory? The way I usually test my extensions is to execute: `drracket my_ext_test.rkt` in the same directory as my compiled directory. That has been an issue for me in the past. Also, if it says the action is forbidden, did you try changing the permissions of your .so? Maybe it's something as simple as that. I'd start with the simple example [Writing Racket Extensions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/overview.html#%28part._.Writing_.Racket_.Extensions%29) and make sure that you can get the hello world program to work in the definitions window. I personally have never had the problem you have mentioned, but I am also running on Linux.

Comment: Thanks, I recently got it working with the final detail coming from the community. It had nothing to do with permissions of the .so but apparently I exported my C-functions to the top-level namespace instead of the module namespace, so I changed  scheme_add_global("function-one",proc,env) info scheme_add_global("function-one",proc,mod_env) and it worked.

Comment: I have put a project using a C-extension on github: https://github.com/marcdinkum/racket_midi Have a look, the Makefile shows how I compile and link. I think I can close this question now, if I knew how to :-)